# Talend : How to keep data in a job, to reuse it later in others components?

Tags: talend

I'm pretty new to Talend. 
I would like to save data that i get from a web service, and re use it later in my job
I could do that using a file or the context, but i wonder if there's a component to do that? Using the context or a concrete file doesn't seems clean to me.
Is that possible, and with which component? 
Thx :)

Comment: if its same job you can try tHashoutput/tHashInput or even look at tBufferOutput/tBufferInput...else flat files are best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its same job you can try tHashoutput/tHashInput or even look at tBufferOutput/tBufferInput...else flat files are best.